# How to fix leak CVPixelBuffer

Tags: iphone, ios, core-video

please tell me where is leak  in this code...

//here I did video with images from Document Directory

```
- (void) testCompressionSession:(NSString *)path
{
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}
NSArray *array = [dictInfo objectForKey:@"sortedKeys"];

NSString *betaCompressionDirectory = path;
NSError *error = nil;

unlink([betaCompressionDirectory UTF8String]);

NSLog(@"array = %@",array);
NSData *imgDataTmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[projectPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:0]]];
NSLog(@"link : %@",[projectPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:0]]);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake([UIImage imageWithData:imgDataTmp].size.width, [UIImage imageWithData:imgDataTmp].size.height);
//----initialize compression engine
NSLog(@"size : w : %f, h : %f",size.width,size.height);
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:betaCompressionDirectory]
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
if(error)
    NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];

NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];
NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);

if ([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput])
    NSLog(@"I can add this input");
else
    NSLog(@"i can't add this input");

[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

dispatch_queue_t    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);

[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:dispatchQueue usingBlock:^{
    //BOOL isEffect = NO;
    int i = 0;
    float totalTime = 0.0f;
    float nextTime = 0;
    if ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
        while (1)
        {   
            if (i <= [array count] && i > 0) {
                nextTime = [[dictInfo objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:i-1]] floatValue];
            }
            totalTime += i == 0 ? 0 : nextTime;
            CMTime presentTime=CMTimeMake(totalTime, 1);
            printf("presentTime : %f  ",CMTimeGetSeconds(presentTime));
            if (i >= [array count]) 
            {
                NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[projectPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:i-1]]];
                UIImage* tmpImg = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                tmpImg = [self imageWithImage:tmpImg scaledToSize:size];
                while ( !writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
                {
                    sleep(0.01);
                }
                CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
                buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tmpImg CGImage] size:size];
                [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(totalTime-nextTime+(nextTime/2.0), 1)];
                NSLog(@"%f",totalTime-nextTime+(nextTime/2.0));
                [writerInput markAsFinished];
                [videoWriter finishWriting];
                //CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
                [videoWriter release];
                break;
            } else {
                NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[projectPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[array objectAtIndex:i]]];
                UIImage* tmpImg = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                //tmpImg = [self imageWithImage:tmpImg scaledToSize:size];
                //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(tmpImg, nil, nil, nil);
                while (!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData && !writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
                {
                    sleep(0.01);
                }
                CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
                buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tmpImg CGImage] size:size];
                if (buffer)
                {
                    if(![adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:presentTime])
                        NSLog(@"FAIL");
                    else
                        NSLog(@"Success:%d",i);
                    CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
                }
            }
    i++;
        }
    }
}];
```

//and here I did CVPixelBufferRef from CGImageRef

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef )pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image size:(CGSize)size
{
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey, 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width, size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, &pxbuffer);

NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL); 

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width, size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
return pxbuffer;
```

leak log is :

CVObject    CFRetain    00:37.957.985   2   0x1ecae0    0   CoreVideo   CVPixelBufferPool::createPixelBuffer(__CFAllocator const*, __CFDictionary const*, int*)
Malloc 96 Bytes Malloc  00:40.015.872   1   0x1f0750    96  CoreVideo   CVBuffer::init()
CVPixelBuffer   Malloc  00:40.969.716   1   0x1f2570    96  CoreVideo   CVObject::alloc(unsigned long, __CFAllocator const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look here:

```
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tmpImg CGImage] size:size];
```

first a pixel buffer gets created and its address put info buffer variable, then the same variable gets overwritten by pixelBufferFromCGImage, so its previous content cannot be released any more.

**EDIT**

you've just removed the code I used, so my answer is now no more applicable.

Now this part:

```
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
buffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[tmpImg CGImage] size:size];
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(totalTime-nextTime+(nextTime/2.0), 1)];
NSLog(@"%f",totalTime-nextTime+(nextTime/2.0));
...
```

You have a commented out CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool), which is okay, since in this version you have not pixel buffer pool, but I miss here a call to CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer).

Comment: just edited: pointed out to another location that looks like leaking a pixel buffer

Comment: Thanks, I was a little yawning... and I have another question... if I append to buffer more images memory used is big and app was crashed...

Comment: Trying to analyse memory without actually trying out would just be quessing game. The best would be to check allocations using Instruments to see where the memory usage comes from. You could periodically mark heap to see if and how fast memory usage grows. Regarding the code in question: it uses possibly a lot autoreleased memory: you could try to create a new autorelease pool and drain it in each loop, thus getting rid of the unnecessary memory immediately instead of waiting for the run loop to do this for you at some time in the future.

Comment: For anyone coming across this nowadays (as I just did), `CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer` is the answer to all your problems. Cheers